# Box api to create enterprise user or group resulting in Invalid parameter

Tags: box-api

I have written the following java code to create a group or box enterprise user. Each time, it fails with the 400. With a lot of trials in the JSON Object input format (more double-quotes,single-quotes,escape character,etc) , I have managed to get error codes right from 400,403,404 and 409. In the process, I have also tried using a string as a json object format.

Lastly, I have created a json object and sent it across to the server using HttpUrlConnection. But still no luck. With a similar code and access token, I have been able to get users/groups/collaborations. But never been able to create the user/group through code. I also tried curl command line and there too I was stuck. My best achievement was that I could get a 403 error using curl command indicating a forbidden or insufficient rights. However, please note that I have generated this access token through enterprise box admin credentials and able to add the user/group through box UI. Also, through code using the above access token I have been able to perform GET. Can someone please point out what I am missing in the code below??

```
URL url = new URI("https", "www.box.com", "/api/2.0/groups", null).toURL();
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
jobj.put("name", "abcdef1");
HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
urlConn.setDoInput(true);
urlConn.setRequestMethod(method)
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");         
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream());
wr.writeUTF(URLEncoder.encode((jobj.toJSONString(),"UTF-8"));
wr.flush();
wr.close();
if (urlConn.getResponseCode() == 200)
{
 //Read buffer    
}
else
    throw new Exception("Reaches HERE!!!!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Box applications using the OAuth 2.0 workflow now support two scopes of accounts access:

```
1. Read and write all files and folders
2. Manage an enterprise
```

The second option -- which seems related to what you're trying to do -- is disabled by default. Have you enabled it for your application?

Comment: Hello John, thanks for the kind reply. Sorry, for the late response. As mentioned by you, i have now enabled the application for managing the enterprise also. But still, am getting the Bad request response (400) .

Comment: Hi Alevi, can you post an HTTP trace of the request that's being sent to Box? This will make it easier to debug the issue.

Comment: Hi John, sorry for the late reply, I have enabled the "manage and enterprise checkbox" in the app and thanks to you, the curl counterpart is working. Here the curl command is :-curl --insecure api.box.com/2.0/groups -H "Authorization: Bearer AUTH-TOKEN" -H "Content-type: application/json" -d "{"\"name"\": "\"family"\"}" -X POST -v. However, the above code continues to give error 400. The I am using NetBeans as the IDE. How can i enable the logging as mentioned by you??

Comment: Hi,
    Any updates on this?? We are having a blocker because of this. We want the Java code to work irrespective of curl command working or not. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Alevi